# Can SCons be used to construct targets from indeterminately named source files?

Tags: scons

I have a directory with multiple source files of indeterminate name. The only thing I know is the file extension. I want to take each source file, and build a single target from each. The method I'm currently using is to determine the name of each source using a for loop:

```
targets = []
for file in listdir('.'):
    if file.endswith('.xdm'): 
        targets += env.m4(source=file)
```

The advantage of doing it progrmatically like this is that the SConscript doesn't have to be maintained by the developers as they add new sources. The problem is that the targets are no longer cleaned because of [something to do with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473808/scons-does-not-clean-all-files) that I don't entirely understand.

So my question is is there a more appropriate way to do this, using in-built *SCons* functionality, without relying on more traditional flow control, or should I just ensure that each of my sources is determined and list them individually in the SConscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with `listdir` I would simply use the `Glob()` method, as provided by *SCons* itself:

```
for file in Glob("*.xdm"):
    env.m4(source=file)
```

This (like the example from your question) is a perfectly fine approach, since it uses the fact that *SConscripts* are actually *Python* scripts. The `Glob()` approach has the advantage of also finding `*.xdm` files that don't exist on the harddrive yet, but may get created as part of the build process later.

I wonder about the problems that you mentioned, regarding cleaning of the targets. The Q&A linked in your question above seems unrelated to me. If you experience actual "cleaning" problems with one of the approaches above, please post a separate question together with the full verbatim input and output. If it should turn out that this doesn't work out-of-the-box, I'd consider it to be a bug.

Comment: Thank you dirk, your solution worked nicely. If I have time, I will take another look at the listdir method later, and if I can't figure out why --clean fails, I will post a follow up question.